# Covert char[2] to uint16_t for socket programming?

Tags: c, tftp

I am writing a tftp client. But when i convert the block number as follows:

uint16_t blockN = buffer[2]<<8 | buffer[3];

after 127, i am getting 65408 as blockN. What might be the problem here?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: you sure you're printing it right?

Comment: i don't remember operator precedence table, but try to use brackets, like `(buffer[2]<<8) | (buffer[3]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing uint16_t blockN = buffer[2]<<8 | (buffer[3]&0xFF);

Answer (score 4):

You have to change the type of `buffer` array from an array of `char` to an array of  `unsigned char`, otherwise `buffer[2]` will be promoted to `int` and sign extension will occur. On most platforms `char` type is a signed type.

Comment: Ok i solved but not exaclty this way but this idea helped. I did  uint16_t blockN = buffer[2]<<8 | buffer[3]&0xFF; so i got rid of sign extensions